# Trouble using OpenCV Histogram Equalisation

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, histogram

I am trying to use `Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalisation` (CLAHE) in `OpenCV`, But getting below error

**Error**
[image]

**Code**

```
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

imgG = cv.imread('sample.png')

clahe = cv.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
imgC  = clahe.apply(imgG)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (20,20))
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(imgC, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Any guess why its happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells that: `(-215) _src.type() == CV_8UC1 || _src.type() == 16UC1`, which basically means that the input mat to `clahe.apply()` can be a **single channel** 8-bit matrix or **a single channel** 16-bit matrix. The `1` in 8UC1 signifies the number of channels expected in the input matrix, since you are reading image as `cv.imread('sample.png')`, so by default it reads 3 channel BGR image. You can either use `cv.imread('sample.png', 0)` or use `img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` after reading the image.